# Compatibility of inline assembly - \n\t versus ;

Tags: c, compatibility, inline-assembly

What is the correct way to write inline assembly (except that avoid it)? Is better to use `;` or `\n\t`?

<sup>(except Microsoft compiler __asm)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not "correct" way to multi-line assembly vs inline. Just whatever is the most readable.

Exemple : `GMP` use differents asm code style for the same `bswap` function

```
/* bswap is available on i486 and up and is fast.  A combination rorw $8 /
   roll $16 / rorw $8 is used in glibc for plain i386 (and in the linux
   kernel with xchgb instead of rorw), but this is not done here, because
   i386 means generic x86 and mixing word and dword operations will cause
   partial register stalls on P6 chips.  */
#if defined (__GNUC__) && ! defined (NO_ASM)            \
  && HAVE_HOST_CPU_FAMILY_x86 && ! HAVE_HOST_CPU_i386   \
  && GMP_LIMB_BITS == 32
#define BSWAP_LIMB(dst, src)                        \
  do {                                  \
    __asm__ ("bswap %0" : "=r" (dst) : "0" (src));          \
  } while (0)
#endif

#if defined (__GNUC__) && ! defined (NO_ASM)            \
  && defined (__amd64__) && GMP_LIMB_BITS == 64
#define BSWAP_LIMB(dst, src)                        \
  do {                                  \
    __asm__ ("bswap %q0" : "=r" (dst) : "0" (src));         \
  } while (0)
#endif

#if defined (__GNUC__) && ! defined (__INTEL_COMPILER)          \
    && ! defined (NO_ASM) && defined (__ia64) && GMP_LIMB_BITS == 64
#define BSWAP_LIMB(dst, src)                        \
  do {                                  \
    __asm__ ("mux1 %0 = %1, @rev" : "=r" (dst) :  "r" (src));       \
  } while (0)
#endif

/* As per glibc. */
#if defined (__GNUC__) && ! defined (NO_ASM)                    \
  && HAVE_HOST_CPU_FAMILY_m68k && GMP_LIMB_BITS == 32
#define BSWAP_LIMB(dst, src)                        \
  do {                                  \
    mp_limb_t  __bswapl_src = (src);                    \
    __asm__ ("ror%.w %#8, %0\n\t"                   \
         "swap   %0\n\t"                        \
         "ror%.w %#8, %0"                       \
         : "=d" (dst)                       \
         : "0" (__bswapl_src));                 \
  } while (0)
#endif
```

Comment: I'd like to add that "\n\t" increases the line counter for diagnostic messages while semicola don't. Messages respecting to large Assembly chunks are therefore more precise.

Comment: So, `\n\t` won the prize. And also, you gave me optimization ideas. Thank you.